# How to make this Go code print in 3 seconds?

Tags: go, time, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Here is the Go code
https://www.intervue.io/sandbox-ILSCXZ6RR

```
func worker() chan int {
   ch := make(chan int)

   go func() {
      time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
      ch <- 42
   }()

   return ch
}

func main() {
   timeStart := time.Now()

   _, _ = <-worker(), <-worker()

   println(int(time.Since(timeStart).Seconds())) // 3 or 6 ?
}
```

How can I make this execute in 3 seconds rather than executing in 6 seconds?

Comment: The code runs in 6 seconds, because you are running the worker Twice. 3+3 = 6s

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It takes 6 seconds because you are receiving from the channel returned by `worker()`, so the 2nd `worker()` cannot be started until a value is received from the first, which takes 3 seconds.

You are using a tuple assignment. [Spec: Assignments:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and **the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation)**. Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

And [Spec: Order of evaluation:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation)

> ...when evaluating the [operands](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operands) of an expression, assignment, or [return statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements), all function calls, method calls, and **communication operations are evaluated in lexical left-to-right order**.

Launch the 2 workers first, and **then** receive from the channels, so the goroutines can truly run concurrently:

```
ch1, ch2 := worker(), worker()
_, _ = <-ch1, <-ch2
```

With this, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KgXwMM5RoFr)):

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove channels since you are not using the result of channels, simply use sync.WaitGroup

```
func worker(n int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("done")
}

func main() {
    timeStart := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i <= 1; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(int(time.Since(timeStart).Seconds())) // 3
}
```

Here is the sample code: https://play.golang.org/p/9_Ymx0tcHqS

Comment: The point was not to simplify the app, because a 3-second sleep and `println(3)` would be equivalent to the desired app. The point was to understand why the original app doesn't complete in 3 seconds.